# Taylor series of square root

Tags: taylor-expansion, radicals

I was reading some paper and I got some Taylor series expansion. I was trying to repeat the process but I can not get same result as the paper:

$\sqrt{1 \pm \frac{1}{n}} = 1 \pm \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{8n^2} + O(\frac{1}{n^3})$

Could someone help me to derive it?

Original paper, 10 equation:

https://www.embedded.com/design/mcus-processors-and-socs/4006438/Generate-stepper-motor-speed-profiles-in-real-time

Edit: I know how to calculate Taylor series, but in particular situation I got lost.

Comment: binomial theorem?

Comment: Do you know how to compute the Taylor expansion of $(1 + x)^{1/2}$? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use
$$\left(1+a\right)^k=1+ka+\dfrac{k(k-1)}{2}a^2+\dfrac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{2\times3}a^3+\cdots$$
with $a=\pm\frac1n$ and $k=\frac12$.

Edit: changed n to k to mach provided hint and a problem.

Comment: Oh, that was my mistake, I was trying to get Taylor series directly by n.